# Android - Insert textview on the touched xy position where views overlap touched close to another view

Tags: android, android-layout, touch, android-relativelayout

Here is the problem I am facing. On a empty relative layout, when touched textview is instantiated at the touched x y position. I got this far correct, but the problem is that when I touch on the empty space near already instantiated view, previous view and currently placed views are overlapped. I tried by the getting the child views of the layout and checking the current view and already placed view using rect data that if they intersect. How to solve this problem?

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private int id = 0;
    private RelativeLayout root;
    private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_designer);

        root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootlayout);
        root.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                switch(event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        instantiateView(v, event);
                    break;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void instantiateView(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        TextView bt = new TextView(DesignerActivity.this);
        bt.setText("1");
        bt.setId(++id);
        bt.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        bt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                showDialog();
            }
        });
        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
        bt.setLayoutParams(params);
        //((ViewGroup) v).addView(bt);

        if(root.getChildCount() <= 0)
        {
            ((ViewGroup) v).addView(bt);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildCount(); i++)
            {
                if (!checkCollision(bt, root.getChildAt(i)))
                {
                    if(bt != root.getChildAt(i))
                    {
                        ((ViewGroup) v).addView(bt);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void showDialog()
    {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
        Button editBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button deleteBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button2);

        editBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

    private boolean checkCollision(View v1, View v2)
    {
        Rect r1 = new Rect(v1.getLeft(), v1.getTop(), v1.getRight(), v1.getBottom());
        Rect r2 = new Rect(v2.getLeft(), v2.getTop(), v2.getRight(), v2.getBottom());

        return r1.intersect(r2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Relative Layout that's why your Textviews are overlapping.

If you don't want the overlapping and want to place it next or somewhere else to the overlapped view , it is your decision. Just check if they intersect and take appropriate decision based on your requirement.

Below line is the problem in your code.

Rect r1 = new Rect(v1.getLeft(), v1.getTop(), v1.getRight(), v1.getBottom());

You set the params' Margin does not mean that you will get desired left,top,right, bottom values.You will get these values right after the inflation of your view hierarchy.

You can use this function:

```
 private boolean checkCollision(View v1, View v2)
{
    int leftMargin = ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v1.getLayoutParams()).leftMargin;

    int topMargin = ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v1.getLayoutParams()).topMargin;

    Rect r1 = new Rect(root.getPaddingLeft() + leftMargin, root.getPaddingTop() + topMargin,
            root.getPaddingLeft() + leftMargin + v2.getWidth(), root.getPaddingTop() + topMargin + v2.getHeight());
    Rect r2 = new Rect(v2.getLeft(), v2.getTop(), v2.getRight(), v2.getBottom());

    return r1.intersect(r2);
}
```

After that use

`params.addRule();` according to your requirement where you want to place your overlapping view.